# Some softwares that can decode CW, AX25, RTTY, PSK etc

Tags: software

What are some softwares that can decode CW, AX25, RTTY, PSK etc? Hope that the softwares provided are freeware or open source.

Comment: Have you tried searching Google? A question like this is never complete and has no correct answer and is not a good fit for Q&A format. It might make a good community wiki question...

Comment: I think this is the sort of information people might come here looking for, but it needs to be changed into a community wiki format where it can be modified as necessary rather than a Q&A format where there is the assumption of a canonical answer.

Comment: @PhilFrost I've just performed a quick search, and was surprised to find that it isn't easy to find.  Can you provide the search string I should use that leads to software that fulfills this answer?  I'm not convinced this is as trivial a problem as you suggest.

Comment: IF this is going to be a wiki it needs to be more specific. Or else the answer needs a WINDOWS, MAC and LINUX section.

Comment: @AdamDavis triviality isn't the problem. The problem is that a correct answer here is not possible. Firstly, because the question doesn't specify exactly the goals ("some", "etc"). Also, it's platform specific. Also, the answer will change over time. All these things are good for community wiki answers, but otherwise not. As it stands, this question manages to hit "too broad", "too localized" and possibly "opinion based" all at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MultiPSK will decode most of those, however AX25 itself is not a modulation scheme, it works at the data link layer, and doesn't specify the physical layer.  More importantly, other applications go on top of AX25 so decoding AX25 by itself isn't that useful.

While many "all-in-one" programs like MultiPSK exist, you may find better results with individual programs for individual modulation schemes, depending on your exact needs.  If you're just casually using them, they might be good enough, but if you're going for a specific use, feature, or need, then you may find specific programs for the one or two schemes you actually use will often have better support for that scheme.

Answer (score 5):

fldigi is multi-platform and will decode many digital modes and has some rig control features available. Check at http://www.w1hkj.com/Fldigi.html for more information.